# Передать в метод объект класса T

Tags: c++

Всем привет. Я реализую класс списка. У меня есть структура:

```
template<class T> struct object {
   T object; // сам объект
   T *nextObject = NULL; 
}
```

И сам класс:

```
class Queue {
    Object *head;

    public:
        void push_back(???) {
            Object obj = new Object;
            obj->object = ???
        }
}
```

Суть вопроса: какой параметр передавать в метод `push_back`?

Comment: Немного с названиями ошибся, структура не object, а Object

Comment: У вас `Queue` должен быть шаблонным, иначе - **какой** `Object` в нем содержится? Ну а дальше, понятно, что в `push_back` надо передавать или `T`, или `const T&`. Но я бы использовал не присваивание, а конструктор копирования.

Comment: Если у Вас тип шаблонный, то и экземпляр его внутри `Queue` должен быть шаблонным, т.е. `Object<нужный_тип> *head;` со всеми вытекающими.

Comment: И еще - если у вас такой односвязный список, то надо держать еще указатель на конец списка - иначе каждый раз проходить по всему списку, чтоб добавить что-то в конец - это слишком затратно...

Comment: @Harry, да, спасибо, переделал под шаблонный класс. Для начала хочу реализовать однонаправленный список, а после того, как будет работать, сделаю двунаправленный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
template<typename T>
class List
{
    struct Object
    {
        T obj;
        Object* next;
        Object(const T& t):obj(t),next(nullptr){}
    };

    Object * head = nullptr, * last = nullptr;

public:
    void push_back(const T& t)
    {
        Object * obj = new Object(t);
        if (last) last->next = obj;
        last = obj;
        if (head == nullptr) head = obj;
    }

    .......
};
```

Думаю, идея ясна? дальнейшую функциональность написать не проблема?

Comment: Спасибо, в целом все ясно, дальше разберусь)

Comment: Ну, тогда удачи :)